# Using MEF to Import Types that Inherit from a given Interface

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mef, caliburn.micro

**[Note there are questions around this subject, but none that seemingly match this specific case]**

I have two ViewModels that export their own interface types

```
[Export(typeof(ITestExplorer))]
public class TestExplorerViewModel : Tool, ITestExplorer, IDataErrorInfo, IDisposable
{
    // Implementation.
}
```

and

```
[Export(typeof(ITicker))]
public class TickerViewModel : Tool, ITicker, IDataErrorInfo
{
    // Implementation.
}
```

Where `ITicker` and `ITestExplorer` both inherit from the same `ICoreDataProvider` interface

```
public interface ITicker : ITool, ICoreDataProvider { }
```

and

```
public interface ITestExplorer : ITool, ICoreDataProvider { }
```

*I am aware that these two interfaces are essentially the same*, however, they are required as I am using Caliburn micro to launch certain view types with different classes inheriting from each of the above.

My problem is that I wish to `[ImportMany]` `ICoreDataProviders`, but I can't export the above classes as both `ITicker` and `ICoreDataProvider` (or `ITestExplorer` and `ICoreDataProvider`) [multiple exports in a single attribute]. I want to do

```
[ImportMany]
private IEnumerable<IBetDataProvider> dataProviderCollection;
```

but I can't switch my export types to `ICoreDataProvider` as they are currently used to launch views ect.

1. Can I ask MEF to import "all type that implement `ICoreDataProvider`", or does the export have to be explicit?
2. If the answer to the above is "yes", how? If "no", is there another way using MEF?

I am aware I could fudge this using reflection via something like

```
var instances = 
    from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ISomething))
         && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
    select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as ISomething;
```

But I don't like this because I will need all sorts of checks on whether the view is open etc.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't export the above classes as both ITicker and ICoreDataProvider ... [multiple exports in a single attribute]

You can export them as both interfaces, just add the export attribute twice.

```
[Export(typeof(ITestExplorer))]
[Export(typeof(ICoreDataProvider))]
public class TestExplorerViewModel : Tool, ITestExplorer, IDataErrorInfo, IDisposable
{
    // Implementation.
}

[Export(typeof(ITicker))]
[Export(typeof(ICoreDataProvider))]
public class TickerViewModel : Tool, ITicker, IDataErrorInfo
{
    // Implementation.
}
```

Comment: No way, so so simple, how have I missed this!? Thanks very much... +1